# Powershell string array to datagridview

Tags: string, datagridview, powershell-3.0

I am trying to write the contents of a text file to a datagridview. If I iterate through the array lines, I see the strings. When I add the array to a datagridview, I see properties of the file, line numbers, and string lengths -- but not the strings, which is all I want.

```
$LogFileRaw = Get-Content($selected)
```

If I use .Net, I just see the string lengths

```
$LogFileRaw = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($selected)
```

I think that I haven't correctly bound the string array to a DataGridView control. I've found examples of doing this in other languages, but not in Powershell. Can someone can point me to a Powershell example or explain what I'm doing wrong? 
Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Get-Content`, but you need to give your log file content 'column' a name:

```
$LogFileRaw = Get-Content($selected) | % {
   New-Object PSObject -Property @{
      "Log Entry" = $_
   }
}
```

Then you can add this to the datagridview:

```
$array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$array.AddRange($LogFileRaw)

$dataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$dataGridView.DataSource = $array
```

This is much simpler when importing a .csv file because you can use the -header parameter of `ConvertFrom-Csv`.

Comment: Thank you so much. What an elegant solution. 
I'm a newb at PS. This REALLY helped me out.